# What will happen when React encounter an array nested in another?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

When React render an array, a key should be provided for every item in this array. Otherwise, a warning will be given:

```
Warning: Each child in an array or iterator should have a unique "key" prop
```

There is detailed explanation in React Doc about [how to identify keys](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys) and [why we do this](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reconciliation.html#recursing-on-children).

But in [this case](https://jsfiddle.net/neo1102/a9hx8cje/), I find that no warning is given when render an array nested in another.

```
const numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
const listItems = numbers.map((numbers) =>
  <li>{numbers}</li>
);

// 'listItems' is wrapped in an array
ReactDOM.render(
  <ul>{[listItems]}</ul>,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

After debugging, in React, I find `function validateChildKeys`, which is used to validate children's keys:

```
/**
 * file path: react/lib/ReactElementValidator.js
 * Ensure that every element either is passed in a static location, in an
 * array with an explicit keys property defined, or in an object literal
 * with valid key property.
 *
 * @internal
 * @param {ReactNode} node Statically passed child of any type.
 * @param {*} parentType node's parent's type.
 */
function validateChildKeys(node, parentType) {
  if (typeof node !== 'object') {
    return;
  }
  if (Array.isArray(node)) {
    for (var i = 0; i < node.length; i++) {
      var child = node[i];
      if (ReactElement.isValidElement(child)) {
        validateExplicitKey(child, parentType);
      }
    }
  } else {
    // do some other validation
    // ..................
  }
}
```

function `ReactElement.isValidElement(child)` is used to check if a child node should be checked.

```
ReactElement.isValidElement = function (object) {
  return typeof object === 'object' && object !== null && object.$$typeof === REACT_ELEMENT_TYPE;
}
```

When checking nesting array, e.g. `array = [array0,array1,array2]`, array0, array1, array2 are `Array` objects, which have no property named `$$typeof`, so function `validateExplicitKey` will never be called, child node will never be checked, of course, warning message will never be thrown.

I wonder:

1. Does React acquiesce this?
2. What impact that would have when re-render happens?
3. Does it have impact on performance? If does, how to avoid this case when I want to render this code:

   ```
   const Page = (tables) => (
      tables.map((table, idx) => (
         [<Title/>,
           ...(table.get('forms').map((form, aidx) => (<Form/>)))
         ]
      ))
   );
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I think the case you're bringing up is actually described in the comment above `validateChildKeys`:

> Ensure that every element either is **passed in a static location**, in an array with an explicit keys property defined, or in an object literal with valid key property.

Since your `listItems` array is only declared once and not recalculated on renders, React assumes it won't need keys to differentiate elements in subsequent renders.

If you move your array declaration into the render function you will see the error again, even if the array is nested:

```
const numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

// 'listItems' is wrapped in an array
ReactDOM.render(
  <ul>
    {[numbers.map((numbers) => <li>{numbers}</li>)]}
  </ul>,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```